# Como fazer ao carregar uma página colocar foco em um input e cursor ficar após valor que estiver dentro do input?

Tags: javascript, html

Ao carregar uma página estou colocando foco em um input, porém ele coloca o cursor sempre a extrema esquerda, gostar de colocar o foco e que o cursor ficasse depois do texto que estiver dentro do input e não antes como está fazendo

Consegui fazer ele colocar o foco no input mas ele coloca o foco antes do texto que vem junto com input

```
<script>
document.nomeformulario.nomecampo.focus();
</script>
<form name='nomeformulario' action='pagina' method='POST'>
<input name='nomecampo' type='text' value'5'>
<button type='submit'>enviar</button>
</form>
```

no codigo que digitei ele coloca o foco no input e o cursor antes do 5 gostaria que colocasse o foco no input e o cursor depois do 5

A esquerda o que acontece
A direita o que eu quero
[image: Saida Real:]
[image: Saida Esperada:]

Comment: O "exemplo 1" da resposta do Caique Romero deve lhe atender bem. ;)

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: De nada! Boa sorte!